# How to display text when clicked on a <map> component

Tags: html

I want to display a text box over my image when I click on the  compoment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Harta Reghinului</h2>

<img src="harta.jpg" height="800" width="1600" usemap="LocuriDeColectare">

<map name="LocuriDeColectare">
    <area shape="circle" coords="500,500,50">
</map>

</body>
</html>
```

What function or where should I document, please give me some links at least, I can`t find anything suitable. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know Javascript and/or JQuery ?

Comment: I know C++, so i think i can manage js a bit

Comment: I highly encourage you learning JS and JQuery. I'm writing a script you can just copy/paste. (I'm commenting it so it's clear)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm doing volunteering to my school by doing this thing, btw.

Comment: i have to come up with a HTML code that displays an image and than when you click on several parts it displays some info about some stuff.I just need the basics, then i can multiply it and get the job done.

Comment: JavaScript can now do everything that jQuery does. So there is no need for jQuery any longer. Basically you need a click event on `area` and then display a hidden input element or create one on the fly

Comment: A good starting point would be [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/)

Comment: @lumio JS always could do what JQuery does ! JQ is just a JS library. But using JQuery makes it much easier.

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer ... sorry I need to rephrase my sentence. JavaScript can do everything as convenient as jQuery can do nowadays, using `document.querySelector` and `fetch` to name just 2.

Comment: True. But I think some habits have been set up since JQuery exists...

Comment: Omg... i was waiting for your reply for 45 mins and i just realised that i had to click "See 5 more messages"... :))

Comment: @lumio do i have to create a distinct file for the JS stuff that displays all that, or can I just add it in the HTML file?

Comment: You can add it between `<script>` and `</script>` in your HTML as well. Although with bigger projects it might get a bit messy and an external js file might be the better way

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer, I'm not saying that it is wrong to learn or use jQuery but I sure think that jQuery is more and more obsolete. If you don't need to support IE<11 then you don't need jQuery at all. [Read this short article](https://dev.to/belhassen07/why-i-dont-use-jquery-anymore--8nh). There is also nothing wrong if you are still using it. I'm just saying, that it is not needed any longer. Except for complex animation stuff - but there are other tools that help with that as well.

Comment: ok, so i need to develop a function that opens a text box and is triggered by a click event. Thanks!